# How to call internal _burn function in smart contract since burnFrom and burn both are internal functions

Tags: solidity, web3js

We started to work on smart contract project on BEP20 tokens and we deployed a smart contract , now one of my customer wants to burn some tokens but in our contract i saw that _burn and _burnFrom both are interal functions and couldn't able to call them from outside,
so now my question is- how come we burn the tokens since both are internal functions, please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

> Use at your own risk

You cannot call those internal methods if your contract is deployed and it does not have a public method that can invoke those 2 functions.

However, there is another way to burn tokens and it is by sending them to an inaccessible address or contract. This has the same effect as burning but it will not reduce the value that is stored "totalsupply" variable

On the Ethereum mainnet developers/people usually send their tokens to one of these 2 addresses (some contracts don't let you send it to the zero address and therefore you must use the dead address or any other inaccessible one)

Zero Address: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Dead Address: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD

Comment: Thank you for your reply, believe the second option will help us!